# Mixing ASP.NET and MVC routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, routes

I thought I could have friendly URLs for all routes in my mixed ASP.NET + MVC application, but it is not working as I expect. Here is my routing definition setup:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapPageRoute("Design-Fancy", "Design/Fancy/{*queryvalues}", "~/Design/example10.aspx", true);
    routes.MapPageRoute("Design-Simple", "Design/Simple/{*queryvalues}", "~/Design/example5.aspx", true);

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
    );
}
```

While this works to route to the *.aspx pages, Any Razor action tags on the same page that are defined for example as "Home" for the controller and "About" for the Action actually are rendered in the page source as 'http://..../Design/Fancy?action=About&controller=Home'. So, this breaks all the navigation menu URLs, etc. I must be doing it wrongly!

Comment: What does your razor action look like?

Comment: You might try changing the order of your mapped routes by putting the "Default" route before the "Design-Fancy" and "Design-Simple" routes, since routes that are mapped first have higher precedence. However, this might break the normal behavior of your Fancy and Simple routes.

Comment: https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/mixing-aspnet-webforms-and-aspnet-mvc

Comment: Changing the order of the routes registrations did fix the Razor action links. And the links to the .aspx pages is still at least functional. However, They don't end up as friendly URLs in this case (as displayed in the address bar of the browser). I get: http://domain.tld/Design/example10.aspx for the .aspx page. I'm trying to figure out how to keep friendly URLs for all. So, thanks RoteS... this was a partial answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I settled on. I installed the NuGet Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls package. Then I named the .aspx page with a page name that would look good without the extension. Then I set up the routing as follows:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        FriendlyUrlSettings aspxSettings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        aspxSettings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;  // default=Off
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(aspxSettings);

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );

        routes.MapPageRoute("Design-Fancy", "Design/Fancy/{*queryvalues}", "~/Design/Fancy.aspx", true);
        routes.MapPageRoute("Design-Simple", "Design/Simple/{*queryvalues}", "~/Design/Simple.aspx", true);
    }
```

This gives the effect I wanted, and works with my MVC routing, and results in routing to .aspx pages while removing the .aspx extension.